# How to make const some members of a mutable lambda capture list?

Tags: c++, lambda, constants, mutable, const-correctness

`mutable` lambda can change the values of the members of its capture list (that were captured by value). Is there any way to make some members of the capture list remain `const` in the `mutable` lambda?

E.g. I want to change `i` but have `const` `j` in the body of `lambda` in [the following code sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CNo4LW9oJZ9E217T):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int j = 108;
    auto lambda = [i, j]() mutable
    {
        i = 15;
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "j = " << j << std::endl;
    };

    lambda();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Write a struct.

Comment: You can always capture a class with a `const` member: `struct hasI { const int i; }`. Now capture that by value, in a mutable lambda, and `hasI.i` is still `const`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hmm. interesting solution. And I can make this struct local and unnamed, so there would not be a lot of boilerplate here. Could you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @PasserBy Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since simple captures have the exact, cv-qualified type of the thing they capture, you can make the outer variable `const` and thus get a const capture:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int i = 42;
//  ^^^^^

    int j = 108;
    auto lambda = [i, j]() mutable
    {
        i = 15;
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "j = " << j << std::endl;
    };

    lambda();
}
```

Of course if you need to modify the outer variable at some point, you need to make a copy of it first -- or refactor your code in some way to make this a bit tidier.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I possibly want to modify it.

Comment: Isn't it copy initialization really? So the cv-qualifiers should not be carried through.

Comment: @StoryTeller: you tell me -- which rule are you referring to that makes you believe that?

Comment: Well in `auto k = i;` We will not get a const object in `k`. And if we were to use an init-list `i = as_const(i)` `i` would not be const either, one can easily try. I suspect the error you get is because `i` is in fact not captured. It's a constant expression (you can use it to define an array).

Comment: @StoryTeller It looks like [the compilers (*clang++* and *g++* at least) agree with **Kerrek SB**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/205e8f8092225485).

Comment: @Constructor - Compilers make mistakes. Lambda captures and constant expressions are notoriously tricky. It's not about compilers agreeing with anyone *now*. It's about agreement in 2 years when the compiler writers may understand the standard better. Hence my doubts.

Comment: Anyway, @Kerrek, in your example it is indeed a constant expression. However, [you are right in general](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10). It also seems to apply to the case of references. So for instances `auto const& foo_c = foo;` and then `[foo_c]{}` (like in the OP's example), is also going to capture by value (as const). +1

Comment: @StoryTeller It looks very strange, but [this code compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23fb8a71674a7772) (in contrast to my previous example). I can't see any logic here.

Comment: @StoryTeller: From [expr.prim.lambda.capture], combine paragraphs 4 (for the *entity* designated by the simple-capture) and 10 (for "The type of such a data member is [...] the type of the corresponding captured entity". (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10) So to be clear, yes, there's a big difference between the capture `[x]` and `[x = x]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Yes, p10 is the one I linked to when I said you are right in general. `i` is still a constant expression in this example.

Comment: @StoryTeller: even with not constant expression, it is right [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JlG1gWd5JpiszX1i). but indeed, with constant expression no need to capture.

Comment: @KerrekSB: *"I want to change `i` but have `const j`"* -> do "`const int i = 42`"... ;-) `i` != `j`

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think your reasoning in Comment 5 is flawed -- all of that comment is irrelevant to the subject in question: we're not in a variable declaration or in an init-capture, and the capture of `i` is explicit, so odr-use and constant expressions don't come into it. The type of the capture is described by the paragraphs I referred you to, which say that the cv-qualifiers are included in the type of the member corresponding to the capture. Sorry if you already said that later, I'm just trying to catch up with comments...